# Converting XML file with multiple lists having nested lists to R Dataframe

Tags: r, xml, list, nested-lists

I am using a XML dataset from https://ped.uspto.gov/peds/#!/#%2FapiDocumentation. This has multiple lists having nested lists and I need to convert it to a dataframe in R. I went through the guidance provided at https://medium.com/geekculture/reading-xml-files-in-r-3122c3a2a8d9 and have tried to replicate the steps given there. But I am unsure how to proceed further as I have multiple lists with nested lists whereas the link has a single list with nested lists.

These are the steps I have followed so far. Please suggest how to get a dataframe in such a case. Thanks.

```
df3 = read_xml("E:\\IIMU\\Databases\\USPTO\\2020-2022-pairbulk-full-20220613-xml\\2022.XML") %>% as_list()

df3a = tibble::as_tibble(df3) %>% unnest_longer('PatentBulkData')
```

The output obtained is as below.

[Output - df3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcSDR.png)

[Output - df3a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aBfx.png)

Comment: What did you download? Selections on page?

Comment: @QHarr Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: The XML file you are working with. It is available on the website you linked to?

Comment: @QHarr - Thanks for the reply. Yes, I downloaded the xml file from the USPTO portal and then tried to convert it to a data frame in R.

Comment: What does one have to do (the steps) in order to achieve the same download?

Comment: @QHarr - I just clicked on the link for the year-wise files in XML format on the right side of the USPTO web page and downloaded the file for 2022.